# Postgresql - Count and Group BY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this rows in my table:

| id | user_id | target_user_id | message | read_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | Hi! | NULL |
| 2 | 10 | 1 | My account is deactivated! | NULL |
| 3 | 11 | 1 | Hi. I cant see comments! | NULL |
| 4 | 12 | 1 | I can't find posts i liked | NULL |
| 5 | 12 | 1 | I forgot my password | NULL |

I just want to retrieve the number of new chats : 3

Comment: Given that _two_ chats appear to be unread, shouldn't the number of new chats be 2, rather than 1?  Can you add more sample data here?

Comment: And what's the *reason* the count should be 1 / ignore some rows?

Comment: Without read_at is null,the query still returns 2.

Comment: @Stu the count should be 1 because two messages have same user_id

Comment: If you remove `read_at is null` you still have 2 qualifying rows. Are you after a count of how many *users* have unread messages?

Comment: @Stu How do I do this with group by ?

Answer (score 2):

To count unique qualifying users simply count the *distinct* values required; it's not clear if it's the user or target_user the *unread* flag applies to, regardless whichever you want to count:

```
select count(distinct user_id) as UsersWithUnreadMessages
from chats
where target_user_id = 1 and read_at is null
```

Comment: I edited my question and added more sample data.

Comment: Looking at your edit the above should work fine. Have you tried it?